# How to use OWASP Encode.forHtmlContent with JSF <h:outputText> and other output elements from RichFaces?

Tags: html, jsf, xss, richfaces, owasp

I tried to find this in a lot of places, but it is not clearly written anywhere. For example in [this documentation](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-html-sanitizer/) the usage is given only for JSP but not for JSF.

Example used in the documentation :

```
<textarea name="text">
  <b><%= Encode.forHtmlContent(UNTRUSTED) %></b>
</textarea>
```

I need something similar for `<h:outputText ... escape='true'>` (escape attribute is not enough for Cross Site Scripting : Poor Validation).

Answer (score 1):

Just use standard [converter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-page-core001.htm).

```
<h:outputText value="#{value}" escape="false">
    <f:converter converterId="unsafeHTMLConverter" />
</h:outputText>
```

With some custom work like:

```java
@FacesConverter("unsafeHTMLConverter")
public class UnsafeHTMLConverter implements Converter {

    PolicyFactory policy = // your fancy policy

    // (...)

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object untrustedHTML) {
        return policy.sanitize((String) untrustedHTML); 
    }   
}
```